# Why doesn't stopping the nginx server kill the processes associated with it?

Tags: networking, process, services, nginx

When I stop nginx like this on ubuntu 12.04, I get the following errors:

```
$ sudo service nginx stop
Stopping nginx: nginx.
$sudo service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

I have to use [this](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/troubleshooting/emerg-bind-failed-98-address-already-in-use/) to fix it. Why does't stopping the service kill the nginx process? That is confusing!

Comment: Maybe it' the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939072/add-nginx-as-a-ubuntu-service-stop-and-reload-doesnt-work

Comment: Stop nginx, then execute:
    netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'
Paste the line here. Maybe the process status will tell us something

Answer (score 6):

By default start-stop-daemon send SIGTERM to nginx process. It doesn`t guarantee stop process. 
Fix: in file `/etc/init.d/nginx` change in section "stop" string

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid \
```

to

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --quiet --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid \
```

That fix send SIGKILL (kill -9) if SIGTERM don`t stop process.

And ensure please, that path to pid-file `pid /var/run/nginx.pid;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and path `--pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid` in `/etc/init.d/nginx` are the same.

Answer (score 3):

If your system has systemd, use it to kill the service - Root may be needed:

```
systemctl kill nginx.service
```

[More information](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-4.html).

Comment: `systemctl kill` is what you mean?!

Comment: @Ned64 Yes, but I just wrote "use systemd kill" and put the link to the commands (to mean use the systemd kill option, I did not intend to write exact command, which is of course what you wrote, and I did not want to repeat given the link has it). Some editor here has formatted the text to look like systemd is a command and changed the link to 'more information text', after I submitted it.

Comment: It's preferable to repeat the command; links are nice, but answers should be written as though the link isn't there, or if/when it breaks the answer becomes useless