# nginx stop is not working and nginx is creating new process after killing processes

Tags: networking, process, services, nginx

**nginx version: nginx/1.8.0**

I am trying to stop nginx with the following command `/etc/init.d/nginx stop`, however it is not returning any successful message. Then I tried to view the nginx processes with this command `[![pidof nginx][1]][1]` and it returns following pids `58058 58057`.

***My first query is why nginx is not stopping?***

Another thing which I tried is to kill the processes, so as above mentioned **PIDs** I tried to remove them by following command `kill 58058` & `kill 58057`, the processes are kill but amazingly new processes created automatically. When I again checked the with the command `pidof nginx`, this time it returns 2 more new processes `58763 58762`.

***My Second query is how these processes are automatically being created?***

I know following query is off topic, however I also want to make changes to the configuration file under sites-available. ***Is there any way the config file changes will be implemented without restarting nginx server?*** (For this reason I am restarting my nginx) as we generally do with nginx.conf file with this command `service nginx reload` or `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`.

My configurations files with pastebin link are as following

1. [/etc/init/nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/jMwirRv6)
2. [/etc/init.d/nginx](http://pastebin.com/um0cAprw)
3. [/etc/nginx/nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/rz17UF6t)
4. [php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf](http://pastebin.com/wwxxAFKC)

> ```
> root@BS-Web-02:/var/run# cat nginx.pid 
> 58762
> root@BS-Web-02:/var/run# pidof nginx
> 58763 58762
> root@BS-Web-02:/var/run# kill 58762
> root@BS-Web-02:/var/run# pidof nginx
> 3809 3808
> root@BS-Web-02:/var/run# cat nginx.pid 
> 3808
> ```

Tried Following Solutions but didn't work

1. [Why doesn't stopping the nginx server kill the processes associated with it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119037/why-doesnt-stopping-the-nginx-server-kill-the-processes-associated-with-it)
2. [Not able to stop nginx server](https://serverfault.com/questions/228084/not-able-to-stop-nginx-server)

**P.S I am using Varnish on Port 80 and nginx on 8080**

Comment: File `/var/run/nginx.pid` is exist? Which PID it contains?

Comment: @strangeman I have added the screenshot of the PIDs

Comment: @SukhjinderSingh prefer to Paste terminal contents rather than adding screenshot.

Comment: @Tejas added as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

Check [monit service](http://www.tildeslash.com/monit) for nginx configuration in `/etc/monit.d/`.

If it doesn't work, please post your data from `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: How this will tell me why my nginx not stopping and why it is creating new processes every time I kill them?

Comment: The Monit application uses PID file checks to see if an application is still running or not. That implies that a PID file must be available for an application, otherwise monit cannot guard it. If a daemon does not create a PID file, use a wrapper to create one.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Monit#Monitoring_applications_through_monit

Comment: if you have monit, configured for nginx - at time when you will stop nginx, monit will start nginx automaticaly.

Comment: Pls, show your /var/log/messages file

Comment: Can please provide any link how to setup monit on Ubuntu 14. Unfortunately the logs are empty this was the reason I need to restart the server after adding access_log on.

Comment: move monit configuration file for nginx from /etc/monit.d/ to somewhere, and restart monit service

OR you can temporary stop monit service.

P.S. if my answer helped you, mark it pls.